# $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] exception

Tags: php

If am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` to detect if the browser is a mobile browser or not and not displaying the page if it's not a mobile browser.

It works fine but I have a local page that I want to use with an iframe to display the content of the page.

Is there a way to create an exception where my local page is about to display the content on a desktop browser?

For example:

If page is displayed by my local page inside the iframe then bypass the mobile browser restriction.

Any ideas if this can be done at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a session variable set on the large page and check for that in the page in the frame. If the session variable is set, display the desktop version.